# Clear selection when Select2 uses minimumInputLength

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select input field that I am enhancing using Select2 jQuery plugin. I passed the minimumInputLength property to have the user type a few letters before populating matching items. However, I am not sure how a user can clear the selection, if required.

I tried to pass the allowClear property, and while it does show an 'X', the button does not work and the selection remains.

EDIT:

```
jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8f1u48et/
```

Comment: Do you have a placeholder and blank `<option></option>` as the first option in your `<select>`?

Comment: Could you add JSFiddle reproducing the issue, can't see to reproduce it?

Comment: Done creating jsfiddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a `placeholder` property when initializing your Select2 jQuery plugin. It is required by the plugin.

The updated code would look like:

```
$('#members').select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: ''
});
```

You can check a working example on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wz0Loz7/1/). When you have something selected, clicking on the clear button will remove the current selection.

Regarding the fact that the `placeholder` is required with this plugin, there is [a section of the documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#why-is-a-placeholder-required) dedicated to this question, but at the moment, it's not been answered yet...

If you need more control over what is going on, a list of the events that Select2 will trigger during the lifecycle of the components is available in [the documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events).

For example, to attach a listener to the `unselecting` event which is triggered before a selection is removed (like when you click the clear button), you'll use:

```
$('#members').on('select2:unselecting', function (evt) {
  // Do something...
});
```

There is also an annoying bug where Select2 will incorrectly toggles the dropdown menu when clearing and removing selections.

The issue is documented on [their Github](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320) but not closed and fixed yet. Many workarounds are available in this thread like canceling the `select2:opening/closing` events that occur immediately after a `select2:unselect` event:

```
var $element = $('#members');

$element.on('select2:unselect', function() {
  function cancelAndRemove(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    removeEvents()
  }
  function removeEvents() {
    $element.off('select2:opening', cancelAndRemove)
    $element.off('select2:closing', cancelAndRemove)
  }
  $element.on('select2:opening', cancelAndRemove)
  $element.on('select2:closing', cancelAndRemove)
  setTimeout(removeEvents, 0)
});
```

Comment: Clicking on the clear button working after I added placehodler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use [select2:unselecting](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events) event so that when the user click the X the value selected is removed and the select2 panel is no more opened:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#members').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a member",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    allowClear: true
  });

  // when you click on the X....
  $('#members').on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {
    // prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // deselect....
    $('#members').val('');
    
    // inform select2 of deselecting....
    $('#members').trigger('change.select2');
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="members" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="300001">Daniel Akaka Kahikina</option>
    <option value="300002">Lamar Alexander</option>
    <option value="300003">Wayne Allard A.</option>
    <option value="300004">George Allen Felix</option>
    <option value="300005">John Smith</option>
</select>
```